# How to get mouse movement when cursor is locked in screen

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application (game) where I need cursor to be hidden, since the player is supposed to control an entity with a mouse. I also had to lock cursor (set middle of screen position using SetCursorPos in mousemove event handler).

Is there a viable and easy solution to tracking mouse movements?

Right now I have a dirty hack of bool value which allows me to ignore next event handler right after a SetCursorPos method is called. But I don't like it and it doesn't work properly - mouse moves are not precise.

Alas, I cannot use DirectInput in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `GetRawInputData` instead of mouse screen coordinates. It worked like a charm.

In the event handler

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Application::StaticWndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
...
case WM_INPUT: 
{
    UINT dwSize = 40;
    static BYTE lpb[40];

    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, 
                    lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) 
    {
        int xPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
        int yPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
        GameState::Instance()->MoveCursor(xPosRelative, yPosRelative);
        RECT rect;
        //resetting cursor to stay in center
        if(GetWindowRect(Application::Instance()->m_hWnd, &rect))
            SetCursorPos((rect.right - rect.left) / 2, (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2);
    } 
    break;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to explain how to get it to send raw input `RegisterRawInputDevices` and aren't checking if the `MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE` flag is set. also you don't need the BYTE array. you can just use RAWINPUT and the sizeof() it. and this is also raw input. no ballistic motion that users know and expect.